# how to change code when you view the page for second time

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to change

```
'orderby' =>  'date',    
with  
'orderby' =>  'random',
```

when you view the homepage for the second time
could u help me?

```
<?php  
     $type = 'client';
     $args = array(
        'post_type' => $type,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 8,
        'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
        'orderby' =>  'date',
        'order'  =>  'DESC'
    );
     ?>
```

Comment: set cookie for ist time, and check cookie exist in second time..

Comment: Why are you not using `'orderby' => 'random'` from the first time, because the results user will see for the first time will never come second time then what's the use of it...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in following manner:-

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['pageviews'] = (isset($_SESSION['pageviews'])) ? $_SESSION['pageviews'] + 1 : 1;
    $type = 'client';
    if($_SESSION['pageviews'] == 1){
        $order_by_data=  'date';
    }else{
        $order_by_data=  'random';
    }
     $args = array(
        'post_type' => $type,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 8,
        'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
        'orderby' =>  $order_by_data,
        'order'  =>  'DESC'
    );

    echo $type;echo "<pre/>";print_r($args);echo $_SESSION['pageviews'];
    ?>
```

Note:- based on session counter value `$args` will change.Thanks

Comment: show this    
 Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\site\wp-includes\class.wp-styles.php:127) in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\wp-content\themes\site\homepage.php on line 56

Comment: @manu `session_start();`will be on top of your page just after`<?php` tag, not in the middle or end of the page. Also remove empty space at the end of the page.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
     //requires session_start();
     $orderBy = "random";
     if(!isset($_SESSION['visited'])) {
         $_SESSION['visited'] = true;
         $orderBy = "date";
     }


     $type = 'client';
     $args = array(
        'post_type' => $type,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 8,
        'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
        'orderby' =>  $orderBy,
        'order'  =>  'DESC'
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use cookie or session to check if the user visited your page for second time.

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if(!is_set($_SESSION['userVisit'])) {
    $type = 'client';
    $args = array(
     'post_type' => $type,
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'posts_per_page' => 8,
     'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
     'orderby' =>  'date',
     'order'  =>  'DESC'
    );
    $_SESSION['userVisit']=1;
   }
   else {
     $type = 'client';
     $args = array(
     'post_type' => $type,
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'posts_per_page' => 8,
     'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
     'orderby' =>  'random',
     'order'  =>  'DESC'
    );
   }
```

I hope I was helpful

Comment: That could use refactoring as you are duplicating code unnecessarily.